# show()/hide() to put up a busyloading spinner

Tags: jquery

Problem with show()/hide() to put up a busyloading spinner.

This does not work:

```
<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;">
  <img src="busyloading.gif">
</div>


$('#spinner').show();

//some busy task here
for (i=0;i<=10000;i++){
    i++;
}

$('#spinner').hide();
```

---

In the end I got it working with jQuery.ajaxSetup, 
but I still would like to figure out why it was not working with regular show/hide:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({   
    beforeSend: function() {   
        $('#spinner').show()   
    },
    complete: function(){   
        $('#spinner').hide()   
    },   
});
```

---

Additional info: 
seems like there is a difference in chrome vs firefox:
At least in FireFox if I add an alert() before the loop - 
the spinner shows up.
In Chrome - even if I add alert() - there is no spinner.

Comment: What is "some busy task here"?

Comment: For example getting some data, or processing some data. As an example - I just added an empty loop to keep it busy for a while.

Comment: "Does not work" is not an accurate description of behavior. I recommend providing more details as to what you expected and what actually did happen. For example "the spinner picture immediately vanished" would have been quite a good description and would have been a good clue to anyone that this is an issue with async processing => probably AJAX => hide the spinner in the AJAX complete callback.

Comment: There is the big difference between synchronous and asynchronous heavy task. To simulate the former You can use `alert('ok')`, works much better than a short, empty loop.

Comment: As requested - more detailed description:
Expected: spinner shown;  some time inside busytask; spinner hidden;
What actually did happen: spinner did not show at all;

Answer (score 1):

If your "busy task" is being called by ajax, your code will continue executing as ajax is asynchronous. That's why you have to use callback functions to execute code when ajax call is complete.

Comment: But in this example it is a simple loop - no ajax. And it still does not work. Why?

Comment: Increment your number of iterations, with 10000000000 you can see it working.

Comment: Tried a bigger number - just takes longer - same result.

Comment: How bigger? Have you tried the number I have wroten? With this one, the script shows me the spinner while works, and then hides it. You have to choose a number that actually hangs the execution a few seconds. I guess it depends on your computer, browser, OS...

Comment: Insert an alert() after share `$('#spinner').show();`, and you will be able to see the spinner showing and after hiding.

Comment: Additional info: 
seems like there is a difference in chrome vs firefox:
At least in FireFox if I add an alert() before the loop - 
the spinner shows up.
In Chrome - even if I add alert() - there is no spinner.